# Java split text into array then add values

Tags: java, arrays, substring, filereader, trim

So I have this text file:

```
FRAMae Berenice MEITE         455.455
CHNKexin ZHANG                454.584
UKRNatalia POPOVA             453.443
GERNathalie WEINZIERL         452.162
RUSEvgeny PLYUSHCHENKO        191.399
CANPatrick CHAN               189.718
CHNHan YAN                    185.527
CHNCheng & Hao                271.018
ITAStefania & Ondrej          270.317
USAMarissa & Simon            264.256
GERMaylin & Daniel            260.825
FRAFlorent AMODIO             179.936
GERPeter LIEBERS              179.615
JPNYuzuru HANYU               197.9810
USAJeremy ABBOTT              165.654
UKRYakov GODOROZHA            160.513
GBRMatthew PARR               157.402
ITAPaul Bonifacio PARKINSON   153.941
RUSTatiana & Maxim            283.7910
CANMeagan & Eric              273.109
FRAVanessa & Morgan           257.454
JPNNarumi & Ryuichi           246.563
JPNCathy & Chris              352.003
UKRSiobhan & Dmitri           349.192
CHNXintong &Xun               347.881
RUSYulia LIPNITSKAYA          472.9010
ITACarolina KOSTNER           470.849
JPNMao ASADA                  464.078
UKRJulia & Yuri               246.342
GBRStacey & David             244.701
USAMeryl &Charlie             375.9810
CANTessa & Scott              372.989
RUSEkaterina & Dmitri         370.278
FRANathalie & Fabian          369.157
ITAAnna & Luca                364.926
GERNelli & Alexander          358.045
GBRPenny & Nicholas           352.934
USAAshley WAGNER              463.107
CANKaetlyn OSMOND             462.546
GBRJenna MCCORKELL            450.091
```

The first digit is an event code (between one and four). The middle four digits are that competitor(s) score in the event (Ex: Mae Berenice Meite scored 55.45 in event 4). The final digit is the competitor(s) team points which will be added to that team's running total (Meite adds 5 points to FRA's team total).

I have already managed to split each line of next using column digits, like this:

```
team = string.substring(0,3).trim();
names = string.substring(3,30).trim();

String[] numbers = new String[3];
numbers[0] = string.substring(30,31);
numbers[1] = string.substring(31,36);
numbers[2] = string.substring(36);
```

So I now have everything organized like this:

```
JPN Yuzuru HANYU    1   97.98   10.0
RUS Tatiana & Maxim 2   83.79   10.0
RUS Yulia LIPNITSKAYA   4   72.9    10.0
USA Meryl &Charlie  3   75.98   10.0
RUS Evgeny PLYUSHCHENKO 1   91.39   9.0
CAN Meagan & Eric   2   73.1    9.0
ITA Carolina KOSTNER    4   70.84   9.0
CAN Tessa & Scott   3   72.98   9.0
CAN Patrick CHAN    1   89.71   8.0
```

...and so on for the rest of the lines.

The problem is this: I need to combine the four different entries for each team into one. So for example, I want this to be France's output:

```
FRA Mae Berenice MEITE, Florent Amodio, Vanessa & Morgan, Nathalie &  Fabian
22 Points
```

This lists all of FRA's competitors, and combines their team points (the last digit) in each event to total up to 22 points.

I'm not sure how I can accomplish this without just creating separate variables for each country, like usaPoints, fraPoints, gerPoints etc and adding them as I go through and read each line of text, but that will not work because I need the running total of each team's points to be associated with the names of the competitors and the country name so that I can output all of this data together.

Is there a way I can do this with the start I have, or a more efficient way to do it differently from the beginning?

Comment: *"I'm not sure how I can accomplish this without just creating separate variables for each country"* - Hint: use a `Map`; e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: In SQL we would talk about **group** by countries, using sum for points and list aggregation for the names. So yes there is a way.

Comment: Note: not saying do it in SQL, but sometimes a problem can be formulated more precisely using the lingo. As you can see in the answer of anTrodaire it is indeed very close: sum <=> total, List<String> <=> List aggregation... the precise formulation of the problem almost tells the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've read and understood your question correctly, my best suggestion would be to create an object for each country. Something along the lines of the following:

```
public class Country{
    String countryName;
    float totalPoints;
    List<String> competitors
}
```

To get your desired output, you can print the country, each competitor's name from the list (for each string in list...), then the total points. If you want to keep each competitor's score too, you use a `List<Map<String, float>>` in a similar fashion.

You could even store all the countries in a `Map<String, Country>`~

In response to your request for elaboration:

```
Map<String, Country> countries = new HashMap<String, Country>();
Country country;
//...loop to read the file...
country = countries.get(team);
if (country == null) {
    country = new Country();
}
//add information to country
countries.put(team, country);
//...end loop...
```

Comment: Would this mean creating a separate class for each country, or using this one class to output the values for each country as I read them from each line of the file?

Comment: You'd create an instance of the class for each country, and populate/update as you read each line from the file. If you store all the instances in a map, you could create the instances (check the map if the country name is already a key, if so add to it, if not create a new instance then add to it)

Comment: To add lines or competitors to a country create an addCompetitors procedure or similar, which adds the points to the total and the name to the list (+1).

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate further? I'm not sure how to create instances of a class dynamically like you describe.